# temporarily keying a data.table for merging

Tags: r, data.table

I have a keyed data.table, `x`, and realize that I need to merge it using a different multicolumn key.

I want to avoid (i) setting and resetting `x`'s key and (ii) keeping track of copies of `x` with different keys. Here's some sample data and my current approach:

```
require(data.table)
options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)
set.seed(1)
n    <- 10
m    <- 2
samp <- function(n) sample(1:9,n,replace=T)
x    <- data.table(A = samp(n),B = samp(n),C = samp(n),key="A")
y    <- x[samp(m),list(B,C,D=samp(m))]

# this works:
x[,.SD,key="B,C"][y]
#    B C A D
# 1: 7 6 6 5
# 2: 9 4 6 2
```

So that approach works, but I get the comment

> ...j is a named list. It's very inefficient...

The named list is `.SD`. Is there a better or more standard way to do this?

It seems that using `key` or `keyby` without `.SD` has no effect:

```
key(x[,,keyby="B,C"]) # A
key(x[,,key="B,C"]) # A
```

Comment: I think your current option is using `merge(x, y, by=c("B","C"))`. Also, `keyby` is something very different from what you seem to think it is - it's just a `by`, with the only difference being that the end result is keyed by the `by` column(s). But I would like this as a feature (assuming it's not already there and I just don't know how to use it).

Comment: You are right: I never use `keyby`, but just noticed that it gave the desired output in this case. Now that I know what it's for, I wouldn't want to use `keyby` here, since it would combine rows with duplicated values of the temporary key. I didn't even think of using `merge` (having become so used to the x[y] syntax), but that does seem like what I ought to do. If no other answer comes along, maybe I should accept that.

Comment: another option is doing `data.table(x, key=c("B","C"))[y]` (I think how well this option works is case-specific)

Comment: Regarding eddi's answer using `merge`, in `merge.data.table` a copy of `x` and `y` are being made (for your case as the keys don't match the `by` argument). Of course keys are being created on the copy.

Comment: @Arun Okay, thanks for pointing that out. Also, if/when @eddi posts that answer, it should have `all.y=TRUE` to exactly match the question, I think.

Comment: yeah, it will still not be exactly the same as it will have extra columns; given @Arun's point, I like the second option I suggested better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In version 1.9.5**, the `on` argument was added, with this usage note in the [changelog](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/#new-features):

> data.tables can join now without having to set keys by using the new `on` argument. For example: `DT1[DT2, on=c(x = "y")]` would join column 'y' of `DT2` with 'x' of `DT1`. `DT1[DT2, on="y"]` would join on column 'y' on both data.tables.

In this case, since the merge-column names are the same in `x` and `y`, `x[y,on=c("B","C")]` works.

---

**Historical answer (around version 1.8.11)**: [As of version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=986) `[.data.table` will have a `key` argument, which is equivalent to calling `setkeyv` beforehand. It's not exactly what this question is looking for, but I don't see a way of achieving this without copying the entire data (bad imo), so I think this is a reasonable compromise, but please let me know if you think otherwise.

*Edit from Matthew*

Specifically adding an argument named `key` to `[.data.table` was a new suggestion in the last few days that I haven't responded to yet. We've discussed secondary keys in the past, `set2key` for example. Secondary keys won't copy the data.

We'll discuss it off list but I think `key` in `[.data.table` will likely change name or be done differently. Reminder to internet: v1.8.11 is in development, unstable and experimental. When it gets published to CRAN, then it can be relied on.

Comment: +1. Yeah, I like this new option and will probably use it. I've made a longer reply on the mailing list.